# How to project anything in medium(air) like projection in wall, as in a free medium

Tags: optics

I just go through books and the internet. But I didn't get my answer that, can I project light in the middle of the air, or wherever we want, not only on wall. I found neon lasers but it also didn't work.

Comment: This needs a major fix.

Comment: Are you looking for something that will create an image in mid-air?  I can think of one or two things that *might* work, but the development would cost a million dollars or so with no guarantee of success.   So the practical answer is "no".

Comment: Take it easy with the down votes. One reason for capital letters (now fixed) or poor grammar is that English may be a second language or the poster may be young. A reason for unclear questions may be confusion about the topic. Thus a need to ask questions.

Comment: You can create little bright sparks in the air at controlled positions by ionizing air molecules with lasers, and use them to build up 3D shapes, see my answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/148493/59406). If this isn't the sort of thing you're looking for, please clarify what your criteria are.

Answer (score 1):

You only see something if light travels from it to your eye. When you project an image on a wall, light travels in a straight line from the projector to the wall. It does not enter your eye on the way, so you don't see the beam.

when light hits the wall, it bounces in all directions. Some of the light bounces toward you. Again light travels in a straight line. some of it enters your eye, so you do see what is projected on the wall.

Normally a beam of light is invisible unless it is pointed at you. In order to see a beam of light, light has to be scattered out of the beam to you. One way to do that is to put dust or smoke in the air. The picture in [this article](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/chemical-found-cigarette-smoke-causes-heart-disease-379777) shows this. Light is everywhere, but you only see it where it hits the smoke.

So you could project light onto smoke to see an image in the air. But that isn't much different from projecting it onto a wall.